# What is a Response object in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, python-3.x, response

While using **requests** to download a webpage, we store the result of that operation in a **response** object. What I could not understand is, exactly what is stored in the **response** object? Is it the source code of that page in HTML or is it the entire string on the page that is stored?

Answer (score 4):

It is an instance of the lower level **Response** class of the python `requests` library. The literal description from the documentation is..

> The Response object, which contains a server's response to an HTTP request.

Every HTTP request sent returns a response from the server (the **Response** object) which includes quite a bit of information.

You can find all the info you need [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response), and also here is the [github link](https://github.com/requests/requests).

Comment: Here's the urllib.request documentation for Python 3: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

And a link to the documentation to the Requests library:
Requests https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 1):

Server and Client use `HTTP Protocol` to send/receive information.

`response` stores all information from server - `HTTP headers` (for example: cookies, status code) and `HTTP body` (mostly HTML but it can be JSON or file or other)

wikipedia: [HTTP Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

BTW: `request` stores `HTTP headers` and `HTTP body` too. (sometimes `HTTP body` can be empty)